# generating anchor and image tags for fancybox image gallery

Tags: image, tags, fancybox, code-generation, anchor

I have a simple html page and I want to make a very simple gallery to it with fancybox. 
Here is the code for one image:

```
<a class="gallery" href="img/83.jpg"><img src="img/83k.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Problem is, I have 400 of them and I have to make it sequential, like:

```
<a class="gallery" href="img/84.jpg"><img src="img/84k.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="gallery" href="img/85.jpg"><img src="img/85k.jpg" alt="" /></a>
etc...
```

Hand coding it would be such a pain. 
How can I generate all of it?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to generate them in the DOM or in the fancybox gallery only? ... what version of fancybox BTW?

Comment: I just want them in the DOM. (it's fancybox 1.3.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container where you want to generate your galleries like:

```
<div id="galleries"></div>
```

then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i = 83; // select your initial number
 for (i=83; i<=483; i++){ // loop as many images as you need
  $("div#galleries").append('<a href="img/' + i + '.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img src="img/' + i + 'k.jpg" alt="" /></a>');
 } // for
// and set your fancybox script afterwards
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  // fancybox options
 }); // fancybox
}); //ready
```