# Jquery fancybox plugin using arrays in code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, for-loop, fancybox

I've got a Jquery plugin for a fancybox, which I know works when I use the following code:

```
$("a#roomthumb_2237").fancybox({ 
        'href'   : '#2237_Info',
        'titleShow'  : false, 
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic', 
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
});
```

But to stop me having to repeat this code multiple times (with different href values), I'd like to run it in a for loop.

The code I've tried is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rooms_array.length; i++) {
    var d = "#roomthumb_"+rooms_array[i]
    $(d).fancybox({ 
        'href'   : rooms_array[i]+'_Info', 
        'titleShow'  : false, 
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic', 
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
    });
};
```

The original code I took straight from google (it may well have been from stackoverflow, I can't remember), but as soon as I try to put it the loop, I'm lost, since I've no idea how to write it.  I think the href line is wrong, but I can't find anything that explains how to do what I need it to.

I dont know how to write the $("a#roomthumb_2237") as $("a"+d) for example...

Comment: Just a comment: Each `id` value should be unique on the page; ie, `$("a#roomthumb_2237")` should never be necessary, as `id="roomthumb_2237"` should always be unique. Thus, `$("#roomthumb_2237")` should always be used, especially as it's most performant. Sub-selectors of course from there make a lot of sense (using `$("#roomthumb_2237 img")` or `$("#roomthumb_2237").find('img')` for instance). In general, you should try to refrain from any element selector being the base selector like `$('a')`, as well.

Comment: @Jared Thanks for the info.. Always good to know these things..

Comment: Did @jfk answer your question? Marking an appropriate answer as the one selected answer is a best practice here at SO.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think he (doubtfully) answered himself.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I did manage to work it out myself, but SO won't let me mark my own answer as accepted yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own issue.  My loop was fine, the only line of text that was wrong, which is what I thought, was:

```
    'href'   : rooms_array[i]+'_Info',
```

I needed to be:

```
    'href'   : '#'+rooms_array[i]+'_Info',
```

Which now I've noticed, is really obvious... I hadn't added the selector.

*Edit:*
Here is my full code, which now works.  Note - I've chosen random numbers for my array, just to show the idea:

```
var rooms_array = [2235, 2236, 2237, 2238]; 
var reposition = function (){ 
    $('#hidden_stuff').attr('display', "none"); 

    $.each(rooms_array, function(key,value){ 
        var a = '#roomthumb_'+value;  
        var b = '#chosenrate_'+value; 

        if ($(b).length) { 
            var c = $(b).offset();  

            $(a).css({ 
                visibility:"visible", 
                top: c.top -9 + "px", 
                left: c.left + 560 + "px" 
            })
        }
        else{ 
        } 

        $(a).fancybox({ 
            'href'   : '#'+value+'_Info', 
            'titleShow'  : false, 
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic', 
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
        });
    }); 
};
```

Comment: still you are using an `ID` selector for multiple instances within the same document. That for sure won't work in IE (it will open the first only.)

Comment: I have x number of images within <a> tags.  Each of these has a unique ID (relevant to a 'room type ID' taken from a database.  This means each ID will be unique, so it should still work.

I've just checked my original question, and realised I did forget to add the line of code which creates an array "rooms_array".  The fancybox code should then loop through each of these.

Comment: do you mean that you will have a different `$("a#selectorID").fancybox()` script for each `<a>` tag?

Comment: I wanted it in a for loop, as I can't be sure of the number of ID's I'll have, but I can write an array.  I've now changed the script slightly, to us JQuery instad.  The code I'm using is now in the question

Comment: hopefully you won't have thousand anchors, otherwise is going to be a hell of lines of (javascript) code, without considering the html.

Answer (score 1):

The normal use for the html `<a>` tag is to have the `href` attribute so if you have for instance:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#2237_Info">2237</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#2238_Info">2238</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#2239_Info">2239</a>
```

then you only need a single fancybox script (one and only)

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({ 
        'titleShow'  : false, 
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic', 
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
});
```

Notice that we used `class="fancybox"` because as mentioned previously, you shouldn't use the same `ID` more then once within the same document (`IDs` are unique)

Also notice that you don't need to set the option `href` within your fancybox script since this is taken from the `<a>` tag itself (the `href` option is used when it doesn't exist as an attribute in the selector -or- when you want to "*force*" a different `href` from the selector.)

On the other hand, if what you don't want to do is to write manually all the `<a>` elements but generating them from an array, then check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10093265/1055987

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a class on the href and use a class selector to call FancyBox?

HTML

```
<a href="whatever.jpg" class="fancyboxMe" id="roomthumb_2237">Anchor</a>
<a href="whatever2.jpg" class="fancyboxMe" id="roomthumb_2233">Anchor</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$("a.fancyboxMe").fancybox({ 
        'href'   : '#2237_Info',
        'titleShow'  : false, 
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic', 
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
});
```

Comment: Even if i did that, all my <a> tags would open the same element (in your example code, #2237_info), won't it??  I need each <a> tag to open a different element in the fancybox.

The reason I wanted to use the loop was to not have to repeat the code multiple times, each with a different "href:xx" line...

I don't know how to get the line
'href':'#2237_Info'

to process as
'href' : rooms_array[i]+'_Info'  (code from my 'for' loop)